# PL/SQL invalid ROWID for update

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowid

I try update salary, but get error:

> invalid ROWID
>
> Cause: A ROWID was entered incorrectly. ROWIDs must be entered as
>   formatted hexadecimal strings using only numbers and the characters A
>   through F. A typical ROWID format is '000001F8.0001.0006'.

this is my code

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR get_sls(mgr NUMBER, dep VARCHAR2) IS 
      SELECT * 
        FROM emp_n_m
       WHERE emp_n_m.mgr = mgr 
        FOR UPDATE OF emp_n_m.sal ;
BEGIN 
  OPEN get_sls(7902, 'SALES');
  if (get_sls%notfound) then
     dbms_output.put_line('incorrect mgr');
  else
    UPDATE emp_n_m
       SET emp_n_m.sal = emp_n_m.sal + 50
     WHERE CURRENT OF get_sls;  
    COMMIT; 
  end if;
  CLOSE get_sls;
END;
/
```

Comment: You just opened the cursor. You haven't fetch anything yet, thus `invalid rowid`.  You need to fetch data from it first. Note if you'll do it in a loop, do not commit inside the loop, otherwise you'll get `"fetch out of sequence"` error.

Comment: thank you very much! you helped me

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR get_sls(mgr NUMBER, dep VARCHAR2) IS 
      SELECT * 
        FROM emp_n_m
       WHERE emp_n_m.mgr = mgr 
        FOR UPDATE OF emp_n_m.sal ;
  v_emp get_sls%rowtype;
BEGIN 
  OPEN get_sls(7902, 'SALES');
  FETCH get_sls INTO v_emp;
  if (get_sls%notfound) then
     dbms_output.put_line('incorrect mgr');
  else
    UPDATE emp_n_m
       SET emp_n_m.sal = emp_n_m.sal + 50
     WHERE CURRENT OF get_sls;  
    COMMIT; 
  end if;
  CLOSE get_sls;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the cursor really required in your case? Would it not be efficient to get this done in a DML operation?

All you want to do is to update salary for manager 7902 from dept 'SALES ...

```
UPDATE emp_n_m SET emp_n_m.sal = emp_n_m.sal + 50 
WHERE emp_n_m.mgr =  7902
AND dept = 'SALES';

COMMIT;
```